# Play ts files with JavaFx 8

Tags: java, javafx-8

i'm trying to run ts file on Javafx media player, but i'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature!
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:411)
at vod_player.media_player.MyMediaPlayerController.showPlayer(MyMediaPlayerController.java:69)
at vod_player.media_player.MyMediaPlayerController$1.lambda$0(MyMediaPlayerController.java:332)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

is there a way to play ts with javafx?

Comment: As far as [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm) is concerned, there's no way. I don't see any way of adding support from external sources discussed either.

Comment: Here's however an unofiicial way to do it: [link](http://berry120.blogspot.ru/2014/03/expanding-javafxs-media-support.html)

Comment: thanks @M.Prokhorov i will check it out